# What happening here '>>>' operator in java?

Tags: java, operators

I have a simple program here .I know it Shift right zero fill operator. The left operands value is moved right by the number of bits specified by the right operand and shifted values are filled up with zeros.

```
package com.demo.operator;
public class Test123 {

      public static void main(String args[]) {
         int a = 60;      
         int c = 0;

         c = a >>> 2;     
         System.out.println("a >>> 2 = " + c );
      }
    }
```

Output:`a >>> 2 = 15`

Can anyone tell  me .

How to give the output `a >>> 2 = 15` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/absolute-beginners-guide-to-bit-shifting

Comment: If you are getting 15 and you know how the operator works, I'm unsure what is being asked here.

Comment: The output appears to be what you're asking the output to be.

Comment: since right shifting in binary is the same as dividing by 2 (in decimal its dividing by 10), what you've done can be thought of as dividing by 2 and 2 again or dividing by 4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`>>>` is the unsigned right shift operator. Since `a` is 60 and 60 is `111100` in binary, when you shift right twice you get `1111` which is 15.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> is the logical (or unsigned) right shift operator.
```

lets `x= 10000000 00000000 00000000 01100000`

x >>> 4 then `x = 00001000 00000000 00000000 00000110`

you can see the rightmost sign bit is also getting shifted to wards right but this is not true for `>>`.

if `x = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00111100` i.e. `x = 60`

now `x>>>2` so `x = 00000000 00000000 00000000 001111` which is `x = 15`.

Comment: OP states they know what `>>>` does.

Answer (score -1):

Check the docs for the [Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).